# How i can work with AvCaptureSession and OpenAL or an other service to play the sound

Tags: openal, iso, avcapturesession, audioqueueservices

I like to implement a voice chat, i have first capture audio with CaptureSession and when i try to play the audio, i have some problems.

With OpenAL, i can't have the sound, data have been append in the buffer but no sound out, but captureSession not run, OpenAL works just fun with a file.

With Audio Queue Service and AUGraph, sound can out but, it stop captureSession one sound is play.

So, i think is a problem with audio device in and out with captureSession and OpenAL...

Someone know how i can work with AVCaptureSession and OpenAL together or an other service to play the sound data when AVCaptureSession is running????